# Why is an airplane able to increase thrust without moving?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, aircraft

I was just watching some documentaries and saw planes building up power in the turbines without moving. I thought about it and remembered, that this happens before every take off.

So, why is this possible? A planes thrust isn't related to the ground, but to the air, so brakes would just increase friction but won't reliably prevent the plane from starting.

So, how is the thrust compensated? I just don't get the clue.

Comment: It's like you say, the brakes increase friction preventing the thrust from moving the plane. Remember, friction is a force that has to be completely overcome and before that, the plane stays put (but obviously if you add too much thrust the wheels would just start skidding).

Comment: Yep, just put on the brakes.

Comment: Perhaps the brakes were even designed for just such a use!

Comment: I think the big soft wheels help with the friction to keep the plane from moving with this thrust: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CpX1riSTeJc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brakes, m'boy, brakes.

Big planes, not surprisingly, have big brakes. And they are easily capable of locking the wheels up. The engine thrust would have to exceed the static friction breakaway force for that plane's weight before it started sliding down the runway.

Aircraft carriers work a bit differently - when your available thrust exceeds your gross weight (and the aircraft can therefore accelerate straight up) the brakes aren't enough. They use a hold-down bar that is engineered to break in two once the catapault engages. The pieces are then discarded. Rather labor-intensive, but simple and reliable.

Comment: I think, I just got my head clear (after some sleep). To get over the friction of blocked wheels, the thrust would need to be somewhat larger than the weight of the plane as `µ ~= 0.9-1.3`. It's nothing special now, as I am thinking about it. I just forgot, what the physics between blocked wheels and the ground are and remembered the last time, I tried to move a car with blocked wheels.

Comment: µ for rubber on concrete averages about 0.7. So you don't need quite your gross weight, 90% should do it. So a 777 needs about 4x the engine power it has, an F-22 can do it if you leave the ordinance off. And blocked wheels are an obstacle to drive over, not friction. You can make them out of lubed teflon if you want.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, for a short field take off, the pilot's operating handbook instructs you to do exactly that.  The brakes are designed for that.

Comment: Or a bush-pilot float plane style takeoff:  tie tail of plane to tree near shore;  rev engines to full take-off power; get stay-behind volunteer to cut rope with axe; take off!